# WorldWind <-> MapCache <-> MapServer

Tags: wms, mapserver, worldwind

I have a MapCache <-> MapServer setup and running. MapCache is configured for WMS access and is used to cache tiles for specific layers provided by my MapServer. I can access the WMS capabilities and display a tile through my browser by accessing WMS trough MapCache and have verified that it is being cached.

Excellent, just what I wanted.

Next, I setup a WorldWind client to access the MapCache WMS. WorldWind complains that the rootlayer (something MapCache uses to wrap all layers) does not provide a geographic bounding box. WorldWind logs this as severe and starts throwing exceptions. I'm trying to figure out where the problem lies. Does the WMS OGC Standard require the top layer to have a bounding box or is the WorldWind client not WMS compliant? Below is the error messages that I'm seeing. Below that is the getCapabilities response. Below that is the MapCache xml file. Below that is the MapServer map file.

[I have also posted this in the WorldWind forum, but not sure if I'll get a response there.](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?44768-WorldWind-lt-gt-MapCache-lt-gt-MapServer)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Exceptions:**

```
SEVERE: No geographic bounding box given in WMS capabilities for layer rootlayer
SEVERE: No geographic bounding box given in WMS capabilities
SEVERE: WMS capabilities document is missing values necessary for component construction

UpdateSequence: none
ServiceName: OGC:WMS
ServiceTitle: map service
ServiceAbstract: none
Fees: none
AccessConstraints: none
Keywords:  none
OnlineResource: href: [url]http://localhost/mapcache/?[/url], type: null
none
Max width = 0 Max height = 0

GetMap
    Formats:    image/jpeg,     image/png, 
    DCPTypes:
        HTTP, Get, href: [url]http://localhost/mapcache/?[/url], type: null
GetCapabilities
    Formats:    application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml, 
    DCPTypes:
        HTTP, Get, href: [url]http://localhost/mapcache/?[/url], type: null
GetFeatureInfo
    Formats:    text/plain,     application/vnd.ogc.gml, 
    DCPTypes:
        HTTP, Get, href: [url]http://localhost/mapcache/?[/url], type: null

LAYERS
LAYER rootlayer: queryable = false
LAYER bluemarbleJanuary: queryable = false

gov.nasa.worldwind.exception.WWRuntimeException: No geographic bounding box given in WMS capabilities
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.DataConfigurationUtils.getWMSLayerConfigParams(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.wms.WMSTiledImageLayer.wmsGetParamsFromCapsDoc(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.wms.WMSTiledImageLayer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.BasicLayerFactory.doCreateFromCapabilities(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.BasicLayerFactory.doCreateFromCapabilities(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.BasicFactory.createFromConfigSource(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.BasicLayerFactory.createFromConfigSource(Unknown Source)

gov.nasa.worldwind.exception.WWRuntimeException: Creation from configuration file failed Version: 1.1.1
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.BasicFactory.createFromConfigSource(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.BasicLayerFactory.createFromConfigSource(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WMS capabilities document is missing values necessary for component construction
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.wms.WMSTiledImageLayer.wmsGetParamsFromCapsDoc(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.wms.WMSTiledImageLayer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.BasicLayerFactory.doCreateFromCapabilities(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.BasicLayerFactory.doCreateFromCapabilities(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more

Caused by: gov.nasa.worldwind.exception.WWRuntimeException: No geographic bounding box given in WMS capabilities
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.DataConfigurationUtils.getWMSLayerConfigParams(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

**GetCapabilities**

```
<WMT_MS_Capabilities version="1.1.1">
<Service>
<Name>OGC:WMS</Name>
<Title>map service</Title>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost/mapcache?"/>
</Service>
<Capability>
<Request>
<GetCapabilities>
<Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost/mapcache?"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</GetCapabilities>
<GetMap>
<Format>image/png</Format>
<Format>image/jpeg</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost/mapcache?"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</GetMap>
<GetFeatureInfo>
<Format>text/plain</Format>
<Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost/mapcache?"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</GetFeatureInfo>
</Request>
<Exceptions>
<Format>text/plain</Format>
</Exceptions>
<VendorSpecificCapabilities>
<TileSet>
<SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:4326" minx="-180.000000" miny="-90.000000" maxx="180.000000" maxy="90.000000"/>
<Resolutions>
0.70312500000000000000 0.35156250000000000000 0.17578125000000000000 0.08789062500000000000 0.04394531250000000000 0.02197265625000000000 0.01098632812500000000 0.00549316406250000000 0.00274658203125000000 0.00137329101562500000 0.00068664550781250000 0.00034332275390625000 0.00017166137695312500 0.00008583068847656250 0.00004291534423828120 0.00002145767211914060 0.00001072883605957030 0.00000536441802978516
</Resolutions>
<Width>256</Width>
<Height>256</Height>
<Format>image/png</Format>
<Layers>bluemarbleJanuary</Layers>
<Styles/>
</TileSet>
</VendorSpecificCapabilities>
<Layer>
<Name>rootlayer</Name>
<Title>map service</Title>
<SRS>EPSG:900913</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:3857</SRS>
<Layer cascaded="1" queryable="0">
<Name>bluemarbleJanuary</Name>
<LatLonBoundingBox minx="-180.000000" miny="-90.000000" maxx="180.000000" maxy="90.000000"/>
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:4326" minx="-180.000000" miny="-90.000000" maxx="180.000000" maxy="90.000000"/>
<SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
</Layer>
</Layer>
</Capability>
</WMT_MS_Capabilities>
```

**mapcache.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- see the accompanying mapcache.xml.sample for a fully commented configuration file -->

<mapcache>
    <metadata>
     <title>map service</title>
     <abstract>Contains various cached maps</abstract>
    </metadata>

    <cache name="disk" type="disk">
     <base>D:/mapserver/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/cache</base>
    </cache>

    <source name="bluemarbleJanuary" type="wms">
     <getmap>
       <params>
         <FORMAT>image/png</FORMAT>
         <LAYERS>bluemarbleJanuary</LAYERS>
         <MAP>D:/mapserver/data/nasaww.map</MAP>
       </params>
     </getmap>
     <http>
       <url>http://localhost/wms?</url>
     </http>
    </source>

    <format name="PNGQ_FAST" type="PNG">
     <compression>fast</compression>
     <colors>256</colors>
    </format>

    <tileset name="bluemarbleJanuary">
     <source>bluemarbleJanuary</source>
     <cache>disk</cache>
     <grid>WGS84</grid>
     <format>PNGQ_FAST</format>
     <metatile>5 5</metatile>
     <metabuffer>20</metabuffer>
     <expires>3600</expires>
    </tileset>

    <default_format>PNGQ_FAST</default_format>

    <service type="wms" enabled="true">
     <full_wms>assemble</full_wms>
     <resample_mode>bilinear</resample_mode>
     <format>PNGQ_FAST</format>
     <maxsize>4096</maxsize>
    </service>
    <service type="wmts" enabled="true"/>
    <service type="tms" enabled="true"/>
    <service type="kml" enabled="true"/>
    <service type="gmaps" enabled="true"/>
    <service type="ve" enabled="true"/>
    <service type="demo" enabled="true"/>

    <errors>report</errors>
    <lock_dir>D:/mapserver/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp</lock_dir>
    <log_level>debug</log_level>

</mapcache>
```

**Map File**

```
MAP
    NAME WMS_server
    STATUS ON
    EXTENT -180 -90 180 90
    UNITS DD
    CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "ms_error.txt"
    DEBUG 5

    #
    # Start of web interface definition
    #
    WEB
        METADATA
            "wms_title"                  "WMS Demo Server"
            "wms_onlineresource"         "http://localhost/wms?"
            "wms_srs"                    "EPSG:4326"
            "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/html"
            "wms_abstract"               "This demonstration server showcases MapServer (www.mapserver.org) and its OGC support"
            "wms_enable_request"         "*"
        END # Metadata
    END # Web

    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4326"
    END # Projection

    #
    # Start of layer definitions
    #

    ##################
    # Blue Marble January 2004
    ##################
    LAYER
        NAME "bluemarbleJanuary"
        #GROUP "default"
        TYPE RASTER
        STATUS ON

        METADATA
            "wms_title"             "Blue Marble Raster (January 2004)"
            "wms_attribution_title" "NASA Blue Marble (January 2004)"
            "wms_srs"               "EPSG:4326"
        END # Metadata

        TILEINDEX "raster/bluemarble/jan/bluemarble-index.shp"
        TILEITEM "LOCATION"

        PROJECTION
            "+init=EPSG:4326"
        END # Projection
    END # Layer

END # Map
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned that the problem is with mapcache, but you need to make sure  mapserver is providing the information in case mapcache is looking for it to forward as part of the getcapabilities request.

you might also want to post this inquiry to the mapserver user or dev mailing list as the developer of mapcache monitors them.

From the mapserver documentation:

wms_bbox_extended:

```
Description: (Optional) “true” or “false”. If true, bounding boxes are reported for all supported SRS / CRS in the capabilities document. If false, only the bounding box of the first SRS / CRS is reported.
Introduced in 6.0.
```

wms_extent

```
WMS TAG Name: BoundingBox (WMS1.1.1, sect. 6.5.6)

Description: (Optional) Used for the layer’s BoundingBox tag for cases where it is impossible (or very inefficient) for MapServer to probe the data source to figure its extents. The value for this metadata is “minx miny maxx maxy” separated by spaces, with the values in the layer’s projection units. If wms_extent is provided then it has priority and MapServer will NOT try to read the source file’s extents.

For Rasters served through WMS, MapServer can now use the wms_extent metadata parameter to register the image. If a .wld file cannot be found, MapServer will then look for the wms_extent metadata parameter and use the extents of the image and the size of the image for georegistration.
```